# Web-Scraping with rvest doesn't work correctly

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to scrape the reviews of room from airbnb web-page. For example, from this web-page: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8400275

And this is my code for this task. I used rvest packege and selectorgadget:

```
x <- read_html('https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8400275')
x_1 <- x%>%html_node('#reviews p')%>%html_text()%>%as.character()
```

Can you help me to fix that? Is it possible to do with rvest package(I am not familiar with xpathSApply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to extract the comment itself. Looking at the html file, it seems that that is not an easy task, since you have to extract it within the `script` node. So, what I tried was this:

- Reading the html. Here I use `connection` and `readLines` to read it
  as character vectors.
- Selecting the line that contains the review information.
- Using `str_extract` to extract the comments.

For the first two steps, we can also use `rvest` or `XML` package to select the appropriate node.

```
url <- "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8400275"
con <- file (url)
raw <- readLines (con)
close (con)

comment.regex <- "\"comments\":\".*?\""
comment.line <- raw[grepl(comment.regex, raw)]

require(stringr)
comment <- str_extract_all(comment.line, comment.regex)
```